# Difference between static and global variable in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming. Can anyone tell what is the difference between  global and local variable in Java?

Comment: Your question's title and body don't match - are you interested in global vs local, or static vs global?

Comment: The more effort you put into your questions, the better both the quality and quantity of the answers you'll receive.

Comment: You probably need to see this - http://tinyurl.com/6h753dy

Comment: I answered, but I love your comment ;-)

Comment: Java doesn't have global variables. It has fields (which can be static) and local variables.

Comment: He is so new n confused to java ..that his heading and Question differs !! :-)

Comment: Some time ago I answered a similar question with a [list of all types of variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909901/java-only-allowing-global-variables-to-be-static/4910050#4910050) in Java, with some explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a little confused since you refer to static/global in the title, and global/local in your question.

`static` variables are tied to a *class*, and you will have *one instance per class*.

classes can have member variables, and you will have *one instance per instance* of that class.

Note that this is complicated further if you have multiple classloaders. In this scenario you can have multiple class definitions loaded, and consequently, possible multiple static variables.

Answer (score 23):

There is no concept of global variable in the Java programming language. Instead, there are class and member attributes. Class attributes are marked with the static keyword, meaning that they can be accessed without instanciation, while member attributes are tied to an instance of a class.

Little example:

```
public class Person{
    public static final int TOTAL_PERSONS;

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public void setFirstname(String firstname){ ... }
    ...
}
```

With this class, I can use Person.TOTAL_PERSONS, but not Person.firstname. To get/set the first name (without mentionning getters/setters which you'll probably soon discover), you first need to create an instance of that class:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setFirstname("foo");
```

Finally, note that it's possible to create what other languages refer to as global variables. For instance, you can use the Singleton pattern, but anyway, global variables shouldn't be used without valid reasons: [check this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)

Comment: Good explanation among all d answers !! Vote up

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other (good) answers:

```
public class Person{
    public static final int TOTAL_PERSONS = 100;
    public static int numberOfLegs = 2;

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public void setFirstname(String firstname){ ... }
    ...
}
```

Writing the following code:

```
Person foo = new Person();
foo.setFirstname("foo");

Person bar = new Person();
bar.setFirstname("bar");

// At this point foo and bar have different firstname, and both have 2 legs

Person.numberOfLegs = 4;

// At this point foo and bar have different firstname, and they both got a pair of 2 extra (bionic) legs

// Person.TOTAL_PERSONS is a 'constant' and has an unmodifiable value of 100
```

Note this is example code and should not be taken as good practice nor to have any sense. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Global and static variables are very similar . The only difference being static 
variables may be public or private . A public static variable is a global variable in java .

Local variables are specific to a method or a class.Their scope is restricted to the specified method or class.

Answer (score -3):

There are two types of methods. They are `class methods` and `object methods`. `Class methods` are identified with the key word `static`. Any method that does not have a key word `static` is  called an `object method`.  Either can be applied *to a method* or *to a variable*.