# How use a global variable in if statement

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, global

I have this if statement and what to access axeMinDmg. How do i set it as a global variable to so that i can access it within the if statement. Also, how to i set minDmg as a global variable so that i can access outside of the if statement. thanks

```
   // if yes ask what weapon to purchase
   if (name.equals("yes")){
       System.out.println("Select Your Weapon \n axe \n bat \n sword : \n  ");

       Scanner wc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String weapon = wc.next();


    if(weapon.equals("axe")){
    minDmg = axeMinDmg;   
   } else {
       System.out.println();
} // close if statement
```

Comment: global variables are more commonly known as class-level variables.

Comment: For an overview on which variable types are available in Java, see [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909901/java-only-allowing-global-variables-to-be-static/4910050#4910050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables really does not exists in Java. You can create a public static final member of a class and the member will accesible in the same scope as the class (if public everywhere)

```
public class MyClass {

  public static final int axeMinDmg = 20;
```

can be used as MyClass.axeMinDmg from everywhere.

Another way could be to go with an [Enum](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: I am sorry, both axeMinDmg and minDmg are integers. Would that make a difference

Comment: As all members you must declare the type String, int, Double, Object, ArrayList, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare and initialize it outside the

```
 if (condition) {
 }
```

block.  This will allow you to use it within if.

e.g.

```
 String minDmg = null; 
 String axeMinDmg = null;
 if (name.equals("yes")) { 
     ... 
 }
```

Hope I am answering your question as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it in the beginning of your class, so the if statement would be included in its scope.

Comment: This is the if statement i can trying to access